# Conditionally render elements in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component which i am looping over array to print out title and values. I have an event listener which renders a new row of title and values. I have a button in child component which i want do not want to be displayed by default but rendered only when i add new rows. So every 2 rows, there will be one button, for every 3, there will be 2 and so on.

This is my app.js file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Child from './Child.js'

class App extends Component {
   state = {
      myArray: [
       { title: 'Hello', value: 'hello' }
     ]
   }

 addNewField = () => {
    const myArray = [...this.state.myArray, { title: 'Hello', value: 'hello' }]
     this.setState ({
    myArray
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className = "App">
   {
    this.state.myArray.map ( (val,idx) => {
      return (
        <Child
        key = {idx}
        title = {val.title}
        animal = { val.value }
        />
      )
    })
  }
  <button onClick = {this.addNewField}>Add Me</button>
</div>
   )
 }
}
export default App;
```

This is the setup for my Child Component:-

```
import React from 'react'

const Child = (props) => {
  return (
     <div>
        <h3>{props.title}</h3>
        <h4>{props.value}</h4>
        <button>New Block!!</button>
    </div>
   )
}

 export default Child
```

So basically the button in the Child component named `new block` should not be displayed by default but only after every click there after. Thank you.

Comment: Expose a property on the Child component to control the rendering

Comment: hmm i tried to do it with index but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a prop to the parent with the index of the map loop. Then add a flag so only children rendered after the first get the "New Block!!" button:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className = "App">
   {
    this.state.myArray.map ( (val,idx) => {
      return (
        <Child
        key = {idx}
        title = {val.title}
        animal = { val.value }
        renderIndex = {idx}
        />
      )
    })
  }
  <button onClick = {this.addNewField}>Add Me</button>
</div>
   )
 }
}
```

```
import React from 'react'

const Child = (props) => {
  return (
     <div>
        <h3>{props.title}</h3>
        <h4>{props.value}</h4>
        {props.renderIndex > 0 && <button>New Block!!</button>}
    </div>
   )
}
export default Child
```

Comment: @Somethingwhatever Sorry! Just tested and you can't use the key prop like this. You need to pass down the index on another prop. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Awesome!! yeah i have ran into this in the past. it's something to do with the key itself. using the `renderIndex` worked. Thank you